# J2ME: How to set a volume of media?

Tags: java-me

I would like to know how to change, or set value to the media volume, I am currently making a game, that will use the audio volume changing.

It seems to me, that you need to use `javax.microedition.media.Control`, but I don't know how to use this library at all.

Please answer, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `VolumeControl`
https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/control/VolumeControl.html

```java
import javax.microedition.media.control.*;

VolumeControl vc = null;

try {
  vc = (VolumeControl) yourPlayerObject.getControl("VolumeControl");
  vc.setLevel(80);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Levels goes from 0 to 100.